# How to convert a datetime to accountExpires AD Attribute?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am using a `DirectorySearcher` filter that does not work, most probably because of a wrong form of `accountExpires` attribute from Active Directory. I would like to find all expired accounts using LDAP, but how can I convert `DateTime.Now` to `accountExpires` format? I have found lots on converting `accountExpires` to `Datetime` format but not the other way around. For example, I have found an example that says :

```
129383640000000000 is equivalent to Sat, 01 Jan 2011 14:00:00 GMT
```

How can I do it the other way? I know it is the interval of 100 nanoseconds from 1 JAn 1601 , but don't know how to calculate this

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to FILETIME, [as per the specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675098(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
long ftAccountExpires = dt.ToFileTime();
```

In the above example, if you set `accountExpires` to the value of `ftAccountExpires`, the account will expire 30 days from now